# Connecting breadboards with different batteries to a single switch

Tags: batteries, switches, breadboard

I have three different breadboards with ten LEDs & resistors connected in parallel.
All three are powered by a 9v battery.

I was wondering if there would be a way to wire all three batteries to a single switch so I could turn everything?

Here's the breadboard diagram:
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: you said that all three are powered by only one battery .... do you mean that each one is powered by a separate battery

Answer (score 1):

If you have a common ground, you could put the switch between the battery grounds and the breadboard grounds.  If not, you probably need a 3-pole switch.

Comment: I've succeeded with wiring a switch to each breadboard & battery. I was wondering if there would be a way to connect all three breadboards / corresponding batteries to a single switch. Would I be able to do this with a 3-pole?

Comment: Yes, if the common ground doesn't work for you.  A 3-pole switch is essentially 3 switches working off the same button/handle.